# Is there a way to see where SQL call is coming from without using SQL profiler?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We're using SQL Server 2012. When I have activity monitor running, I keep seeing a query pop up on the recent expensive queries list. But I can't figure out where this query is coming from.

I've run a search of all the jobs, functions, and stored procedures, and it isn't anywhere to be found.

This query only shows up during the day, and I can't turn on SQL Server Profiler because our system will grind to a halt.

Is there any system table I should search, or query I should try  in order to determine where the call is coming from?

Comment: You could use Extended Events; that are far less invasive than Profiler.

Comment: I've never used Extended Events, can you provide more details?

Comment: My knowledge of them is limited as I haven't used them often. Grant Fritchey has done some extensive articles on them though.

Comment: You can use this tool https://expressprofiler.software.informer.com/download/

Comment: Although I recommend an Extended Event trace to a file target, you can similarly script a Profiler session for server-side tracing to a file target. This has minimal impact compared to Profiler.